# get_Property() uses a TrySomething() method with an "out" parameter. How to store the "out" value?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a `PizzaLover` class. In this class, there is the `CanAffordPizzas` property:

```
public bool CanAffordPizzas => 
    TryBuyPizzas(this.numDollarsInBankAccount, out uint numAffordablePizzas)
```

`this.numDollarsInBankAccount` is a private property.

I need the information contained in `numAffordablePizzas` whenever I call `CanAffordPizzas`. I tried the following, which doesn't work:

```
public uint NumAffordablePizzas;
public bool CanAffordPizzas => 
    TryBuyPizzas(this.numDollarsInBankAccount, out uint this.NumAffordablePizzas);
```

Another option that I can see is to declare the variables `numDollarsInBankAccount` and `numAffordablePizzas` every single time I need to invoke `TryBuyPizzas(decimal numDollarsInBankAccount, out uint numAffordablePizzas);`, but that is unsatisfactory for these reasons:

- It would require me to expose the (currently private) property `numDollarsInBankAccount` in the `PizzaLover` class.
- It leads to code duplication.
- There is no guarantee that the caller will always pass `pizzaLoverInstance.NumDollarsInBankAccount` as the first argument.

What is an elegant solution to achieving what I want?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here. *Why* do you need the variable? It doesn't appear that the property uses this particular value at all.

Comment: And a property really shouldn't have side effects, so maybe you shouldn't declare this property at all and instead create a method that calls `TryBuyPizzas` with the correct parameters but exposes an `out` parameter for that affordable pizzas value?

Comment: So if you need this value *outside* of the property, then no, there is no easy way to fix this and still use the property *because a property is the wrong answer*. Declare a method with an out parameter instead.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Very good points! I will re-factor the current design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest, and in my opinion, *more correct*, solution, would be to simply rewrite the property to a method:

```
public bool CanAffordPizzas(out uint numAffordablePizzas)
    => TryBuyPizzas(this.numDollarsInBankAccount, out numAffordablePizzas);

public bool CanAffordPizzas()
    => CanAffordPizzas(out _);
```

---

Note that I'm using the new "discards" support in C# 7 which you can read more about here: [Discards - C# Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards).

If you don't have C# 7 support just yet you need to create a "discard" variable of your own in that second method:

```
public bool CanAffordPizzas()
{
    uint discard;
    return CanAffordPizzas(out discard);
}
```

---

If you're forcing the user of your class to explicitly make a read of a property in order for some other property or variable to be updated, that is an anti-pattern and is usually solved by splitting up everything or rewriting to make the state impact clear.

The "split" would be to have the type not care (or know) about "affordable pizzas" but have your "try buy" method return a new object that does care (know), so that the only way to get to the object that knows this value is by going through your property or method.

Since in this case, this second value *is* that parameter, you're best of just exposing that part yourself.

Comment: Thank you! I like your suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

```
public bool CanAffordPizzas => 
    TryBuyPizzas(this.numDollarsInBankAccount, out uint this.NumAffordablePizzas);
```

The `out uint xxx` declares a *new* variable `xxx` of type `uint`. To refer to an existing variable, omit the type:

```
TryBuyPizzas(this.numDollarsInBankAccount, out this.NumAffordablePizzas);
```

Comment: Duh! Thanks for pointing that out -- it is something that I already know, but obviously I am having a massive brain-fart today!

Comment: Though having to explicitly *read* a property (and not get that read optimized away by the JITter because you're not using the result) in order to get the side effect of another property/variable being updated is an anti-pattern.